# Armadillo installation

Tags: c++, g++, installation, armadillo

Hi I installed Armadillo3.0.1 in my own working directory /home/me/package/armadillo3.0.1/ as the README.txt said. But when I try an example:

> g++ -I /home/me/package/armadillo3.0.1/usr/include/ example.cpp -o example -O1

It always shows the error:

> /tmp/ccZAE9pj.o: In function `void arma::gemm<false, false, false, false>::apply_blas_type<double>(arma::Mat<double>&, arma::Mat<double> const&, arma::Mat<double> const&, double, double)':
>   example.cpp:(.text._ZN4arma4gemmILb0ELb0ELb0ELb0EE15apply_blas_typeIdEEvRNS_3MatIT_EERKS5_S8_S4_S4_[void arma::gemm<false, false, false, false>::apply_blas_type<double>(arma::Mat<double>&, arma::Mat<double> const&, arma::Mat<double> const&, double, double)]+0x75e): undefined reference to`wrapper_dgemm_'
>   /tmp/ccZAE9pj.o: In function `void arma::glue_times_redirect2_helper<true>::apply<arma::Mat<double>, arma::Mat<double> >(arma::Mat<arma::Mat<double>::elem_type>&, arma::Glue<arma::Mat<double>, arma::Mat<double>, arma::glue_times> const&)':
>   example.cpp:(.text._ZN4arma27glue_times_redirect2_helperILb1EE5applyINS_3MatIdEES4_EEvRNS3_INT_9elem_typeEEERKNS_4GlueIS5_T0_NS_10glue_timesEEE[void arma::glue_times_redirect2_helper<true>::apply<arma::Mat<double>, arma::Mat<double> >(arma::Mat<arma::Mat<double>::elem_type>&, arma::Glue<arma::Mat<double>, arma::Mat<double>, arma::glue_times> const&)]+0xe69): undefined reference to`wrapper_dgemv_'
>   example.cpp:(.text._ZN4arma27glue_times_redirect2_helperILb1EE5applyINS_3MatIdEES4_EEvRNS3_INT_9elem_typeEEERKNS_4GlueIS5_T0_NS_10glue_timesEEE[void arma::glue_times_redirect2_helper::apply, arma::Mat >(arma::Mat::elem_type>&, arma::Glue, arma::Mat, arma::glue_times> const&)]+0x1175): undefined reference to `wrapper_dgemv_'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

However if I add the -larmadillo option like:

> g++  example.cpp -o example -O1 -larmadillo

It works by calling the old version. If I want to use new features in 3.0.1 like Mat.t(), it will also show the error:

> example.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
>   example.cpp:20: error: ‘struct arma::mat’ has no member named ‘t’

This shows that by adding -larmadillo, it calls the old version armadillo from /usr/include/armadillo_bits/.

Any idea of that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first command, you are not linking with *libarmadillo*. Have you considered using the *-L* gcc option to add a link directory ? For example:

> g++ -I/home/me/package/armadillo3.0.1/usr/include/
>   -L/home/me/package/armadillo3.0.1/usr/lib example.cpp -o example -O1 -larmadillo

Comment: Thanks, it seems work. Now it doesn't print out arcane errors but only  complaining cannot find libmkl.so.

Comment: You probably need a similar -L and -l for libmkl.

Comment: I've ran into a similar problem. I installed armadillo without root permissions and I guess I need to tell g++ where headers and the library are. Therefore, I've done the following:      
      g++ -std=c++0x example.cpp -o example -O2 -I/my_directory/armadillo-9.100.5/include -L/my_directory/armadillo-9.100.5/libarmadillo.so.9.100.5 -lblas -llapack  
  
  Now, for some reason I don't understand if I add the -larmadillo option to include the run-time library, I get an error telling that -larmadillo couldn't be found. Any ideas what might be wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I've also run into this issue.  I've fixed it by uninstalling any previous versions of Armadillo, as they can interfere with the new version.

Uninstallation can be done via your package manager. You can also manually remove the old version via the following commands (in a terminal window):

```
   rm /usr/include/armadillo
   rm -rf /usr/include/armadillo_bits
```

You'll need to run the above commands as a super-user (root).  On Ubuntu it should be sufficient to preface them with "sudo".

You may also need to remove the old library files, which could be in /usr/lib/ or /usr/lib64/, or something along these lines.

Once the old version has been removed, you can re-install the new Armadillo, via the cmake based installation.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the old one and reinstalled the new one in default directory. It worked! 
So it seems when I installed the old version with:

> make install DESTDIR=my/own/dir/

it was install incorrectly.

Hence for newbies like me, install by default makes more sense.