# Installing Armadillo without root permission

Tags: cmake, permissions, installation, armadillo

I've been trying to install the C++ armadillo library in a cluster environment for which I don't have neither root nor sudo privileges. So far, I haven't had much success. 
Following some system admin basic guidelines, the armadillo README file and the instructions provided [here](https://github.com/masumhabib/quest/wiki/How-to-Install-Armadillo), I've arrived to what I understand it is the installation part:

```
"cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=<desired directory>
```

In "desired directory", I've introduced the folder where my codes are located.

Then I did

```
make
```

and

```
make install
```

and went back to the directory where I had installed armadillo. I tried compiling my code and got the message:
"error: armadillo: No such file or directory"
My assumption was that the system was simply not seeing the library at all. I was then advised by system admin to change the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH in order for the compiler to know where to look. I proceeded to do so by:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:<desired directory>
```

only to get the same error again. ("desired directory" is the directory where my codes and library live).

I suspect I might be making some very basic mistake, but that's my first time trying to solve such problems. Therefore, I'd appreciate any help and would be thankful for your patience.

Comment: The message "error: armadillo: No such file or directory" doesn't look like the linker cannot find the library. It looks more like `armadillo` **executable** isn't found, as it contains no extension. As the latter case is weird (no executable is shipped with the `armadillo` package), it seems that you passed wrong parameters to your project. Anywhere, given error message is too short for make conclusions why **your code** isn't build. [Hint: Show your code].

Comment: Hello @Tsyvarev and thanks for your answer. I actually tested in some of the example codes provided within the library. In particular, I took "example1.cpp" to the folder that contains my codes (and also the library, I thought), tried the compile and got the same errors as with my own code:
example1.cpp:2:21: error: armadillo: No such file or directory

Comment: If you open the file referenced by the error message (`example1.cpp`), then you will find `#include <armadillo>` in its second line. It is the **header** which is missed, not a *library*. If you build example with Makefile shipped with it, open this file and you will discover these comments: `## If you've installed Armadillo's headers manually, you may need to tell the compiler where they are.`, `## For example, change ../include to /usr/local/include`.

Comment: I've tried to go back to this and have some questions. My guess is that #include <armadillo> is a call to the header (is a header a file that calls the library in itself, perhaps?). Somehow, the compiler doesn't know where the header for armadillo is and that's why I get that error. As I don't know how to use "makefile", I tried to use the '-I' option when calling g++, i.e.: g++ example.cpp -o example -I Directory/include. Does this make any sense?

Comment: Yes, you may use `-I` option for hint the compiler about include directories.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev! So I've tried that but unfortunately doesn't work either and I get the same error as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168181/armadillo-installation). I've tried the 'L' option as well because it is my understanding that this tells the compiler where the actual library is. It didn't work either. I do not have any older versions installed, so I don't know what could be wrong now. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [Questions](http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html) page from the Armadillo website, one approach is to simply use the `-I` option to gcc or clang.  If you have unpacked armadillo in `/home/sergio`, the following should do the trick:

```
g++ prog.cpp -o prog -O2 -I /home/sergio/armadillo-9.100.5/include -DARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER -lopenblas -llapack
```

Change the `-lopenblas` to `-lblas` if the machine that you are using doesn't have [OpenBLAS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openblas/files/) installed. (OpenBLAS is a fast version of BLAS).

Comment: This has worked very well, many thanks! Was this because somehow openblas and lapack live in different directories than Armadillo?